# Cannot resolve Method 'replace (int)' for Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

im using the Navigation Drawer Activity and im stucked at one problem. I get this error message

```
Cannot resolve Method 'replace (int)
```

I was watching a tutorial but the guy doesnt get the error message somehow. I was also trying to solve the problem by reading other posts but it confused me even more.

My Code looks like this:

```
MainActivity.java

package androfenix.mycvapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_aboutme) {
            FragmentAboutme fragmentAboutme = new FragmentAboutme();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment).commit(fragmentAboutme);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_cv) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_skills) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_projects) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_download) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_website) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the layout fragment which i want to replace is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout_for_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="androfenix.mycvapp.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here [FragmentTransaction.Commit()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit()) does not Require an Arguement

so instead of:

```
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment).commit(fragmentAboutme);
```

use:

```
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment, fragmentAboutme).commit();
```

Also make sure your `FragmentAboutme` is extending the support library

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Study about fragments

```
replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,"your about me fragment").commit();
```

why would you even pass fragment object in commit() method there is no such method;

Comment: Omg im so dumb! Thanks.. i wrote it into the wrong bracket.. "fragmentAboutme" should go into the replace part

Comment: Yeah so before asking any question here please study thoroughly about any topic refer docs here https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/topics and here https://developer.android.com/index.html